# How can I remove non-breaking spaces in my aws athena table?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, datagrip

I have timestamp stored as a string [imported from csv].
string :`2022-05-04[NBSP]02:46:35`

actual string: `2022-05-04 02:46:35`

the middle space is a nonbreaking space and prevents casting to timestamp.

I have tried

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET myts = REPLACE(myts, CHR('00A0'), '')
```

I get an error that the connector I am using does not support updates, both in datagrip and in the athena editor within the AWS console.

I want to convert this to a regular space in order to cast to timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While an update can't be done, a new view can be created on top of the existing table and referenced downstream. The syntax for replacement `myts = REPLACE(myts, CHR('00A0'), '')` will remove the space entirely -- to get the desired format casting as timestamp, it should be

```
myts = REPLACE(myts, CHR('00A0'), ' ')
```

If there there a large volume of data, until the point at which it is later filtered, it's inefficient to materialize for each cleaning operation, and best to use a view rather than materializing with a CTAS.